# Chef/Ruby Adding IP after some text if we have no matches

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to add a line with a node IP after an existing line to a config file. The first time when I run the recipe It goes ok but the second time when it checks for a matching (I try to avoid a line duplicating using If statement) it shows me the error. Here is the recipe code sample:

```
IP=node['ipaddress']

ruby_block 'Inesrt IP' do
if File.readlines('file.conf').grep(/#{IP}/).size < 1
        block do
                file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("file.conf")
                file.insert_line_after_match(/someline/, "TCPAddr #{IP}")
                file.write_file
        end
end
end
```

Here is the error:

```
NoMethodError
    -------------
    undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
```

I am newbie in ruby and chef. Thanks in advance for a help.

Answer (score 1):

FileEdit is an internal class to Chef and is not part of our public interface. Look at the community cookbooks like poise-file and line instead.